# ReactJS object filter get undefined on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use `map` to get `data` in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const DistrictOptions = Data.DistrictData.map((obj) => ({
    key: obj.id,
    text: obj.name,
    value: obj.id,
    cid: obj.cid
  }));

console.log(DistrictOptions); // return data successfully
}
```

And it return data successfully, now I want to do a filter on this object, I treid:

```
const DistrictOptions = Data.DistrictData.filter(x => x.cid === 1).map((v, i) => {
  return {
    key: i,
    value: v.id,
    text: v.name
  }
});
```

But this return empty array `[]` I also tried this:

```
const opt = DistrictOptions.find(x => x.cid === 1);
```

But this return `undefined`, confusing what happen here and what I done wrong.  this is `Data.DistrictData`:

```
const Data = {
    DistrictData: [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ss 1",
        "cid": "1"
      }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "ss 2",
        "cid": "1"
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "ss 3",
        "cid": "1"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: in `Data` your `cid` value is a `string` and your filter query you are trying with `number`. you can replace with `x => x.cid === '1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `==` comparator for comparing `cid` as shown or use `===` operator and convert your `cid` to number:

#### Using ==

```
const DistrictOptions = Data.DistrictData.filter(x => x.cid == 1).map((v, i) => {
  return {
    key: i,
    value: v.id,
    text: v.name
  }
});
```

#### Using ===

```
const DistrictOptions = Data.DistrictData.filter(x => Number(x.cid, 10) == 1).map((v, i) => {
  return {
    key: i,
    value: v.id,
    text: v.name
  }
});
```

You can also use `parseInt(x.cid,10)` for a conversion to integer.